# ASP.Net WEB API WebService - Config File

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm writing a .Net WEB API WebService. And I would like to have a configuration file to be able to manage settings. Whats the preferred way for a configuration file in a ASP.Net WebA PI project?

Thank you!

Comment: Same as all config files in .Net, AppSettings

Comment: depends on what version of asp.net you are using. If it's <= 4.5.x then you have the web.config file, if you are using asp.net core than you have no limits, you can use whatever config file you want and just register it in the startup.cs file.

Comment: I used configuration sections to implement my config. It works great.